Spring Modulith Transactional Event Publication stalls JDBC Connections
Introduction
I recently introduced Spring Modulith in one of our applications, and used the @ApplicationModuleListener to listen to events published from a method within the application, annotated with Spring's @Transactional. The entire setup works as expected. Events are published with records of it written to a table (event_publication) in our database.

The issue here is that the application get stuck after a few runs because there are no more available JDBC Connection in our connection pool to handle further requests from operations/threads that needs it.

Explanation Below
Currently, the application is structured in this manner:
class AppScheduler {
    final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 120_000, fixedDelay = 120_000)
    public void execute() {

        final String operationID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(ApplicationCustomEvents.AEvent(operationID));
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(ApplicationCustomEvents.BEvent(operationID));
    }
}

class AEventListener {

    final ALogicsAggregator aLogicsAggregator;
    
    @ApplicationModuleListener
    void on(ApplicationCustomEvents.AEvent evt) {
        aLogicsAggregator.execute(evt);
    }
}

class BEventListener {

    final BLogicsAggregator bLogicsAggregator;
    
    @ApplicationModuleListener
    void on(ApplicationCustomEvents.BEvent evt) {
        bLogicsAggregator.execute(evt);
    }
}

//Similar design BLogicsAggregator as well
class ALogicsAggregator {
    final ALogic1 aLogic1;
    final ALogic2 aLogic2;
    final ALogicN aLogicN;

    void execute(AEvent evt) {
        //Distribute operations to ALogic1... ALogicN, depending on some known conditions
        //Each of the logic 1...N, are executed one after the other.
        //The operation within each logic is held as a SET and are run in parallel
        //At some point in ALogic's execution Network calls are made to external systems
        //At some point in ALogic's execution READS and WRITES are done to the DB
        //Separate Transactions are opened for the WRITE action to the DB
        //Within the logic, parallel executions are initiated where necessary
        aLogic1.excute(Set<Opertaions>);
        aLogic2.excute(Set<Opertaions>);
        aLogicN.excute(Set<Opertaions>);
    }
}

Since I use spring-data-jpa, I have Hikari Connection pool defaults auto-configured, when I first encountered the error, I thought the configured defaults wasn't enough, I tried to tune the pool size (increasing it above 10 and reducing it below ten). After a few runs, the application begins to throw errors - that it cannot acquire a JDBC Connection.
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [AppDBConnPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30005ms (total=5, active=5, idle=0, waiting=2)] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:274) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]

When I look at the Hikari JMX Bean on JConsole, I see that the connections in the DB Connection Pool are actively been used but never released, and there are at least one thread/operation waiting to acquire a DB connection (if ever it becomes available).
My Attempt to Fix
I am not sure where the issue is coming from in particular, but when I remove the @Transactional from the event publication class, and replace Spring Modulith's @ApplicationModuleListerner in the listener classes with @Async + @EventLister (from Spring), even with a DB connection pool-size of 5, the application never stops. There are some points when most/all available DB connections in the pool are being used, but they're eventually released and other operations/threads picks and use them again, I didn't encounter a situation where the connections were held for longer than usual.
My hypothesis
I have a wild guess that between the transaction created/opened at the point where the event was published and those opened when I write to the DB mess things up, I can't tell how or why, and without the @Transactional annotation on the event publisher method, the event listeners marked with @ApplicationModuleListener cannot pick up the published events.
Please help/advise on what I might be doing wrong and how I can solve this issue.
Thank you

I might have just figured out what the problem is and a possible solution.
Problem
@ApplicationModuleListener by definition is composed of @Async, @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) and @TransactionalEventListener.

For me, the issue was with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW), and according to Spring Modulith Doc., the intention is to run the event listener in it's own transaction.

While this might not be a bug in itself, for my use case the event listener calls a class which fans our requests to other classes (subclass), and within these subclasses, there were WRITES to the Database (requiring new transactions). This meant that, either the subclass had to wait on the initial transaction opened by the event listener to complete (commit) or it might hook onto the transaction created by the event listener, and I'm not sure either case is ideal - at least for me it hugs the DB Connection from the pool forever.
Solution
To Solve the issue, I replaced the usage of @ApplicationModuleListener with @Async and @TransactionalEventListener like so:
class AEventListener {

    final ALogicsAggregator aLogicsAggregator;
    
    @Async
    @TransactionalEventListener
    void on(ApplicationCustomEvents.AEvent evt) {
        aLogicsAggregator.execute(evt);
    }
}

class BEventListener {

    final BLogicsAggregator bLogicsAggregator;
    
    @Async
    @TransactionalEventListener
    void on(ApplicationCustomEvents.BEvent evt) {
        bLogicsAggregator.execute(evt);
    }
}

Doing this immediately solved my problem, I even configured the hikari connection pool-size to 2, and the application didn't stop working.
I came about this solution after watching a VOXXEDDAYS YT video from 6 years ago which suggested that there is no need to use @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) whenever the event lister is tagged with @Async. He proposed that the @Async annotation will make the listener run in a different scope (thread/context) from the publisher (which technically makes it a separate transaction on its own)
Recommendation
Maybe the Spring Modulith project can have a variant of the @ApplicationModuleListener which isn't laced with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
